# why does this showing error while calling facebook embed api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, embed

```
data=requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oembed_post?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fphoto%3Ffbid%3D2432221750211842&set=a.105613599539347&access_token=access-token")
print(data.json())
```

*when i try to fetch html for post from facebook api,its showing error like below.i want html code but it showing error*

**error**

{'error': {'message': '(#10) To use this endpoint you must first add the OEMBED product to your app.', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 10, 'fbtrace_id': 'AeELX_E5zJZVMGtnQbNGSni'}}

Comment: Didn’t the error message pretty much just _tell you_ why? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed#oembed-product

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation:
[Facebook for devs #oEmbed Product](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed#oembed-product)

> In order to access the endpoint you must **add the oEmbed Product to your app**. You can do this by **signing into the App Dashboard, selecting your app, clicking the Products link, locating oEmbed, and adding the Product.**